# MySQL What the meaning of using x(Value) before inserting selection?

Tags: mysql, sql

I just wonder what is the meaning or what happens when you use a 'x' infront of the value in MySQL for example below SQL query ?

```
SELECT onoffid FROM DSLServiceOnsandOffs WHERE insertDate='2017-02-14' AND 
`Service_No`=x'323439533313034' AND `PON`=x'33330343230' AND
`Order_No`=x'393313833' AND `Segment_No`=x'31' AND 
`Completion_Date`='2017-02-13' AND `On_Off`=x'4f4e'
```

Comment: That makes it a hexadecimal constant:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/hexadecimal-literals.html.  It seems rather silly for those values.  One would expect a smattering of As, Bs, Cs, Ds, Es, and Fs, such as for `On_Off`.

Comment: Those are hex values, which means you've got some really odd junk in those fields. That `Service_No` value converts to `249S3\x13\x03@`